# Guice runtime dependency parameters reinjection

Tags: java, guice

A question about Guice. I'm still learning it, but I can understand the fundamentals.

This question was already asked a couple of times on the net, but never with a concrete answer(none that I could find).

Say I have a situation like on the picture(a similar example was somewere on the net).

[image]

```
public class Dog {}

public class Walk implements Walkable {
    private final Dog dog;
    private final boolean leash;

    @Inject
    public Walk(Dog dog, @Assisted boolean leash) {
        this.dog = dog;
        this.leash = leash;
    }

    public void go() {
    }
}

public interface Walkable {
    void go();
}

public interface WalkFactory {
    Walk create(boolean leash);
}

public class AssistedMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            protected void configure() {

                install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().
                        implement(Walkable.class, Walk.class).
                        build(WalkFactory.class));
            }
        });

        Walk walk = i.getInstance(WalkFactory.class).create(true);
    }
}
```

That's all great. But the question is - can I, somehow, reinject that object instance to the "container"(injector) to be used on the classes that rely on this dependency.

So, lets add a `interface Person`, `class PersonImpl`.

[image]

The new classes source are:

```
public interface Person {
    void walkDog();
}

public class PersonImpl implements Person {
    private Walkable walkable;

    @Inject
    public PersonImpl(Walkable walkable) {
        this.walkable = walkable;
    }

    public void setWalkable(Walkable walkable) {
        this.walkable = walkable;
    }

    public void walkDog() {
        walkable.go();
    }
}
```

So, the question is - am I, somehow able to actually inject this particular instance into the added object. This is a simple example, but we can presume there are 10 levels of classes below this one.

The solution I found is not very flexible. Something like:

`Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new SimpleModule(false, dog));`

And then bind to concrete instance. That's not very dynamic. Basically, every time I need a different runtime/dynamic parameter I have to recreate the injector.

The `Provider<T>` is nice, the `FactoryModuleBuilder` helps, but how can I inject the objects back?

**Are there more dynamic solutions to this problem?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MPierce - agreed. Ill try to explain the way i visualized the problem(you can correct me if im wrong).

Being originaly derived from a "service locator" pattern, the idea that it can manage more than services is optimistic to say the least.

We could split the application into **Service and Data classes**, or you could say that we have **application and infrastructure code** - "Dependency Injection", a great book.

So, basicly, dependecy injection, and dependency injection frameworks in general are great. **For solving infrastructure, or "service" code.**

Any dynamic(runtime) parameters being injected into the Container/Injector are basicly **forcing you to end the object graph**.

For example, we have the folowing design:

[image]

EmailMessage is a runtime parameter. It can be "injected" into email service outside the Container/Injector, but it ends the object graph. **If we want to request EmailDispatcher, after we injected the EmailMessage into EmailService(which is, I repeat, done outside injector), we could no longer fetch EmailDispatcher from the injector.**

Then, you could redesign your model so it "fits" into the Container/Injector concept of dynamic parameters.

[image]

But then again, you forced the design, and suddenly, **EmailDispatcher has too many responsibilites**. It could be used in such a context, where you dont have many infrastructure classes.

[image]

And when you have a design like you have in the third example picture, you cannot use the Injector/Container to fetch you a NextService3 instance(nor any below the level of EmailDispatcher).

The problem being - **if you have any dynamic(runtime) parameters, you can only use dependency injection for classes above the class that requires a dynamic parameter, you can forget the classes below.**

Phew.

Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem depends on how you're resolving that 'false' is the thing you want to set for the leash field. Is that coming from config data or what?

A provider method may be helpful...

```
class FooModule extends AbstractModule {
...
    @Provides
    Walkable getWalkable(Dog dog) {
        boolean leash = getBooleanFromSomewhere();
        return new Walk(dog, leash);
    }
}
```

If you can clarify where that boolean is coming from, it'll help me to understand what type of approach is applicable.

Comment: The leash is a dynamic parameter somewere in the application. Lets say that this parameter is provided by the user somewere in the application(there is a leash checkbox :) ). The user can check and uncheck that checkbox and expect a Person to Walk the Dog with or without the leash. The "problem" is that that parameter is dynamic, and would require "reinjection" into the "container", so the "infrastructure" object graph can instanciate objects accordingly to that parameter. This is a simple example, say you have 30 users, and you want to aquire UserTransaction for each one, depending on login.

Comment: I see. Perhaps injection is not the right tool for this, then. Injection is often awkward when the parameters that define injection are driven by user data. (Argh, I cannot put a newline in a comment?) You could try using request-scoped injection where the stuff that gets injected depends on parameters you determine by inspecting the authenticated user, or refactoring your API a bit to allow 'leash' to be provided as a method parameter instead of a field in your objects. Not really the answer you're looking for, I realize, but I think you're stretching the limits of what IoC does well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom scopes](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes), much like when using guice servlets. That way you can create your instance, and then seed it in the injector.

Comment: A good idea, but not really solving the problem. The problem is the dynamic reinjection, in the "Binding the annotation to the implementation", the example instanciates the instance from within the injector. The same functionality could be achived with passing an object to guice before it is initialized(that would be even more dynamic). The point being, custom scopes are usefull, but not in this context - I still have an instanciation in the injector, which means its a statically initialized container, not really giving me any flexibility over the object injection.