# Guice: How to change injection on runtime based on a (dynamic web property)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

The following is an approximation of the problem I'm facing.

Think we have a password validator with some rules.

```
public interface RuleChecker{

    //Checks for a password strenght, returns 10
    //for strong or 0 for soft password.
    int check(String pass);
}
```

And then we have several implementations, our service will only accept the password if it is over 8 score.

```
public class NoCheck implements RuleChecker {
    public int check(String pass){return 10;}
}

public class LengthCheck implements RuleChecker{
    ...
}
public class AlphanumericCheck implements RuleChecker{
    ...
}
public class AlphaAndLenghtCheckAdapter implements RuleChecker{
    ...
}
```

But for testing purposes, we want to implement a webservice within the application where we can "admin" those rules, and select which ones to have.

```
public class PasswordCheckService{

     private RuleChecker checker;

     @Inject
     public PasswordCheckService(final RuleChecker checker){
         this.checker = checker;
     }

     public boolean checkPassword(String password){
         return checker.check(password) > 8;
     }
}
```

So, is there any way in Guice, to change at runtime, the injection a service has?

Example:

We started the application and by default LengthCheck is selected and injected on the application, at the website we select the NoCheck checkbox and save options, which is stored into the database, can I configure Guice to automatically change the bean the service had injected before? so from now and on there will be no checks on new passwords?

--

As for now, I have found those topics

[Google Guice and varying injections at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651980/google-guice-and-varying-injections-at-runtime)
But i dont know if that kind of providers fits my problem.

[Guice runtime dependency parameters reinjection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641565/guice-runtime-dependency-parameters-reinjection)
That nice question is talking something similar, but not what I'm looking form.

[guice: runtime injection/binding at command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663618/guice-runtime-injection-binding-at-command-line)
This is the closest to my problem but he only does on starting "runtime" and does not change it over the time.

Any helps?

Thank you!

Using the tip of the first comment I implemented this POC but still does not works, if you change select another button the service bean is not updated.
https://bitbucket.org/ramonboza/guicedynamicconfig

Comment: Good question.  I've been trying to do something very similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a provider for each field type (login, password, birth date...), with a parameter to change the implementation to return.

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    public void configure() {
       bind(RuleChecker.class).annotatedWith(named("password")).toProvider(PasswordRuleCheckerProvider.class);
       bind(RuleChecker.class).annotatedWith(named("login")).toProvider(LoginRuleCheckerProvider.class);
    }
}

public static class PasswordRuleCheckerProvider implements Provider<RuleChecker> {

    private static CheckType type = CheckType.ALPHANUMERIC;
    // static type setter.

    public RuleChecker get() {
        // it would even be better if you could use singletons here.
        switch(type) {
            case LENGTH:
                return new LengthCheck();
            case ALPHANUMERIC:
                return new AlphanumericCheck();
            case ALPHALENGTH:
                return new AlphaAndLenghtCheckAdapter();
            case NONE:
            default:
                return NoCheck();
        }
    }
}
// Almost same provider for your LoginRuleCheckerProvider. You could do something generic.
```

In your admin section you change "type" value, so your rules will change. It can affect a limited set of fields, thanks to the annotations. For instance : `PasswordRuleCheckerProvider.setType(CheckType.LENGTH);`. Will only affect fields with `@Named('password')`.

You have to declare your fields and services like this :

```
public abstract class DynamicService {
    protected void updateService() {
        // Reinject with the new implementations the members.
        App.getInjector().injectMembers(this);
    }
}

public class PasswordCheckService extends DynamicService  {
    @Inject
    @Named("password")
    private RuleChecker passwordChecker;

    public void changePasswordCheckType(CheckType type) {
        PasswordRuleCheckerProvider.setType(type);
        // Reinject, so you have your new implementation.
        updateService();
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: I'm gonnna do a PoC to try your approximation ;), hope to be back in a couple of hours (lunch time now xD)

Comment: Updated topic, implemented the POC with no luck, check
https://bitbucket.org/ramonboza/guicedynamicconfig

Comment: Managed to get it working locally. I've updated the post. You just have to reload dependecies and keep the field 'type' static in your provider.

Comment: isn't this line against inversion of control rules? App.getInjector().injectMembers(this);

Comment: In this small snippet, it's against IoC rules, because it's inside the service. But you can use this line from the provider itself for instance. This way, the service isn't aware of what's going on.

Comment: I will mark your solution as accepted because I found no other way than getting new elements. There are two solutions, one is exposed on my bitbucket code, that you call in the own code for singletons to be used `App.getInjector().getInstance(RuleChecker.class);` the other one, and a bit more elegant, which I will use on trunk, is to create a Custom Scope which will be used to define which Beans must be reloaded after every `getInstance(Clazz)` call