# Dynamically Injecting into Google Guice bean

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using constructor DI with Google Guice.

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyOtherClass otherclass

    @Inject
    MyClass(MyOtherClass otherClass) {
         this.otherClass = otherClass
    }
}
```

to get an instance of MyClass, I do:

```
com.google.inject.Injector.getInstance(MyClass.class)
```

All good.  However, now I have two different versions of MyOtherClass.  So I, need something like:

```
public class MyClass {

    MyInterface myInterface

    @Inject
    MyClass(MyInterface myOtherInterface) {
         this.myOtherInterface = myOtherInterface;
    }
}
```

}

I need to be able at runtime, instantiate a 
`MyClass` with either a `MyOtherClassA` or `MyOtherClassB` instance.

So in one code path I need something like:

```
 com.google.inject.Injector.getInstance(MyClass.class, MyOtherClassA)   // A myClass sinstance which points to MyOtherClassA
```

and in another code path, I need:

```
 com.google.inject.Injector.getInstance(MyClass.class, MyOtherClassB)   // A myClass sinstance which points to MyOtherClassB
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve that

> - Binding Annotations

Create the following Annotations class

```
public class Annotations {
  @BindingAnnotation
  @Target({FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD})
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  public @interface ClassA {}

  @BindingAnnotation
  @Target({FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD})
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  public @interface ClassB {}
}
```

Add the bindings in your module class

```
bind(MyInterface.class).annotatedWith(ClassA.class).toInstance(new MyOtherClassA());
bind(MyInterface.class).annotatedWith(ClassB.class).toInstance(new MyOtherClassB());
```

To get the necessary instance use this

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(MyInterface.class, ClassA.class))
injector.getInstance(Key.get(MyInterface.class, ClassB.class))
```

MyClass constructor will look like this

```
@Inject
MyClass(@ClassA MyInterface myOtherInterface) {
   this.myOtherInterface = myOtherInterface;
}
```

> - @Named

Use the following bindings

```
bind(MyInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("MyOtherClassA")).toInstance(new MyOtherClassA());
bind(MyInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("MyOtherClassB")).toInstance(new MyOtherClassB());
```

To get the instance use this

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(MyInterface.class, Names.named("MyOtherClassA")))
injector.getInstance(Key.get(MyInterface.class, Names.named("MyOtherClassB")))
```

MyClass constructor will look like this

```
@Inject
MyClass(@Named("MyOtherClassA") MyInterface myOtherInterface) {
   this.myOtherInterface = myOtherInterface;
}
```

Please, refer to [Guice documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) for more details.

Comment: thanks but this just gets me an instance of MyInterface not an instance of MyClass?

Comment: Thanks, but that means MyClass has to know about the various implementations MyInterface - albeit with a layer of indirection with the annotations.  What I wanted was the the person creating MyClass to decided what version of MyInterface would be used - this is easy in vanilla java. But seems tricky in guice

Comment: Have you seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358487/guice-how-to-change-injection-on-runtime-based-on-a-dynamic-web-property